# Is there a way to query a backup database without restoring it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2005 instance running and a client of mine deleted some data that they would like to get back. It is four records. Is there a way to query the backups to see if the data exists without restoring the database?

They just noticed the data was missing and it could have been deleted by them 3 months ago or yesterday, so the backups could have been overwritten and it not exist at all. I am just trying to cover my bases to see if I can find the data before telling them they should not of clicked OK the second time when I asked them if they were sure they wanted to delete that record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RedGate sells [Virtual Restore](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-virtual-restore/), which can

> Rapidly mount live, fully functional databases direct from backups

You could sign up for a trial and check your current backups.

P.S. I haven't used Virtual Restore, but the other RedGate products I used were of good quality.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>No, there is not that posibility, but,</strike> if your backup media are files, (in example with diferent names in a folder), you can make a loop script to automate the restore each one and a subsequent query to the missing records.
The script just need to do `restore database ... from ...`  if you want I have a similar script but not accesible to me now.